# MX records for individual email addresses on GoDaddy?

Tags: dns, godaddy, cpanel, mx, zoho

I have an `info@mycompany.com address` in Godaddy.  I also created a couple email addresses in Zoho mail e.g. `user1@mycompany.com` and `user2@mycompany.com`.

If I set up an MX record to point my user1 and user2 address in Godaddy will the `info@mycompany.com` address still work?  Can I have some email accounts configured in Godaddy and others in Zoho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can I have some email accounts configured in GoDaddy and others in Zoho (for same domain)?**

No you cannot. MX records are set on a domain (or subdomain) level.

Comment: To add to this, I just looked in my GoDaddy cPanel to make sure.  You must either 1. delete the info address from godaddy, and then recreate it at zoho, and then modify the MX record so that you're all Zoho, or 2. Add all the addresses from Zoho to GoDaddy, and drop Zoho

Comment: Yeap I'm doing number 1 right now and zoho has a migrate features that moves the emails! pretty cool.. but I get an error when I try to point the mx to zoho. It doesn't accept mx@zohomail.com as a host. error is: Mail server's address example: smtp.secureserver.net

Comment: Because that is not a correct hostname nor record. Please consult your providers documentation on how to properly set these or ask new question.

Comment: that is what the documentations says though :S https://adminconsole.wiki.zoho.com/domains/MX-Records.html#step1

Comment: nevermind it was a godaddy issue with their new control panel. After switching to the old one I was able to add the mx records

Comment: https://adminconsole.wiki.zoho.com/domains/MX-Records.html#Instructions_to_add_MX_records_-_GoDaddy